# Yii2 Connecting to a MYSQL DB inside a Docker Instance on another server

Tags: php, mysql, docker, yii2

I have this situation:

I have a few servers inter connected in a datacenter, for example:

- Server 1 internal ip: 10.0.0.1
- Server 2 internal ip: 10.0.0.2
- Server 3 internal ip: 10.0.0.3
- Server 4 internal ip: 10.0.0.4
- Server 5 internal ip: 10.0.0.5

I need to create a connection in Yii2 from server 10.0.0.1 to server 10.0.0.2 but the only way I can see this database in 10.0.0.2 is first creating a tunnel via SSH to that server and then creating the connection to the localhost with the specific port assigned in the docker container (at least that's how I have it setup on heidisql).

I have no idea how to create an SSH tunnel with Yii2 before the new DB connection.

So far this would be my db2.php file would be:

```
   return [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=33008;dbname=test_db',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'attributes'=>[ PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 6000, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE ,  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'select 1', ],
        'enableSchemaCache'     => true,
        'schemaCacheDuration'   => 600,
        'schemaCache'           => 'cache',
]
```

I'm just missing the SSH tunnel so I can connect to 10.0.0.2

I hope someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: [This](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/mysql-through-ssh-tunnel/49506) is quite old topic but maybe it can be of help.

Comment: I've seen this article a few times already, but it's not clear on how to do it plus the version they use for this case is Yii V1 which Im using Yii 2